# Joomla 3.3 Captcha not working on Chronoforms,Acymailing and RSForms

Tags: php, joomla, captcha, joomla3.0, chronoforms

I am currently sitting with the problem of getting 'incorrect' captcha's from Acymailing, RSforms, Chronoforms5 and chronoforms V4. I have tested on xampp, wamp, live hosting and a bunch of others, In case it was my on my side. I do have the latest Joomla installed.

I work with a group of people and we all have the same issue, Here is what happens:

This is the captcha that i get (chronoforms5):

[image]

If I enter that captcha it fails, however if I open Firebug and inspect the image, this is what i see:

[image]

Now if i enter that captcha its successful, And I have this issue with virtually all of the captcha's on this website, including: RSforms, Chronoforms and Acymailing.

Any Help with this Issue would be Fantastic.

Comment: Is this captcha a built in feature of these extensions or is it some sort of remote validation such as ReCaptcha?

Comment: nope its all built in the extensions.

Comment: In which case I would suggest that you contact the developer of the extension you're using as they will be able to provide a better solution to the problem.

Comment: fair enough, but 3 extensions from 3 separate developers that have the exact same issue, has lead me to believe that its not really the extensions fault.

Comment: I'm not really too sure as I haven't used either of these extensions in a very long time. It might be that they are all using the same remote validation like recaptcha or coincidentally are using the same built in validation. Either way, would be best to ask them first ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end it was empty image tags `<img src="" />` or empty `background:url();`. I have no Idea why. But after an entire day, I finally figured it out. Thank you all for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a conflict between CAPTCHA and the Joomla cache.

Try temporarily disabling the cache if cache is enabled to see if this fixes the issue for you.